# Using DataTables with Python

Tags: python-3.x, datatable

I'm a beginner at website programming and want to understand some basics.

I've created a Python 3 script which fetches some data from a website and makes some calculations. Result is then about 20 rows with 7 columns.

What is the easiest way to make them available on my website? When refreshing my website, the Python script should fetch the data from the 3rd party website and this data should then be displayed in a simple table with sorting option.

I've discovered the jQuery plugin DataTables with Ajax JSON source. I would create a PHP script which executes the Python script which writes data to a DB like MariaDB. PHP then creates a JSON for Ajax.
Is this the right way or are there easier ways? Maybe using a framework etc.?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier than I thought, there is no need for PHP and MariaDB.
When using nginx, you need uswgi and uswgi-plugin-cgi to let nginx know that the Python script is a script and not data. Point to the Python script in the Ajax parameter of the DataTable JS code, make it executable and print the array with JSON function in the Python script, and include cgi/json header strings. The array should look like that in the example of Datatables Website (Ajax source).
It's all running in the memory now.